# asynchronous programming in python

Tags: python, asynchronous

Is there a generic notion of asynchronous programming in python? Could I assign a callback to a function, execute it and return to the main program flow immediately, no matter how long the execution of that function would take?

Comment: related http://nichol.as/asynchronous-servers-in-python

Comment: There are quite exciting [new developments in the field](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3221314/asynchronous-programming-in-python/18099524#answer-18099524).

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Take a look here:

[Asynchronous Programming in Python](http://xph.us/2009/12/10/asynchronous-programming-in-python.html)

[An Introduction to Asynchronous Programming and Twisted](http://krondo.com/blog/?p=1247)

Worth checking out:

[asyncio (previously Tulip) has been checked into the Python default branch](https://plus.google.com/103282573189025907018/posts/6gLX8Nhk5WM)

#### Edited on 14-Mar-2018

Today Python has [asyncIO — Asynchronous I/O, event loop, coroutines and tasks](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html) built in.

Description taken from the link above:

> The **asyncIO** module provides infrastructure for writing single-threaded
>   concurrent code using coroutines, multiplexing I/O access over sockets
>   and other resources, running network clients and servers, and other
>   related primitives. Here is a more detailed list of the package
>   contents:
>
> 1. a pluggable event loop with various system-specific implementations;
> 2. transport and protocol abstractions (similar to those in Twisted);
> 3. concrete support for TCP, UDP, SSL, subprocess pipes, delayed calls,
>      and others (some may be system-dependent);
> 4. a Future class that mimics the one in the concurrent.futures module, but adapted for use with the event loop;
> 5. coroutines and tasks based on yield from (PEP 380), to
>      help write concurrent code in a sequential fashion;
> 6. cancellation support for Futures and coroutines;
> 7. synchronization primitives for use
>      between coroutines in a single thread, mimicking those in the
>      threading module;
> 8. an interface for passing work off to a threadpool,
>      for times when you absolutely, positively have to use a library that
>      makes blocking I/O calls.
>
> Asynchronous programming is more complex
>   than classical “sequential” programming: see the [Develop with asyncio
>   page](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-dev.html#asyncio-dev) which lists common traps and explains how to avoid them. Enable
>   the debug mode during development to detect common issues.

Also worth checking out:

[A guide to asynchronous programming in Python with asyncIO](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/a-guide-to-asynchronous-programming-in-python-with-asyncio-232e2afa44f6)

Comment: That's not really an answer.

Comment: Which part of that answers the question "Could I assign a callback to a function, execute it and return to the main program flow immediately, no matter how long the execution of that function would take?"

Answer (score 59):

What you describe (the main program flow resuming immediately while another function executes) is not what's normally called "asynchronous" (AKA "event-driven") programming, but rather "multitasking" (AKA "multithreading" or "multiprocessing").  You can get what you described with the standard library modules `threading` and `multiprocessing` (the latter allows actual concurrent execution on multi-core machines).

Asynchronous (event-driven) programming is supported in the standard Python library in the `asyncore` and `asynchat` modules, which are very oriented to networking tasks (indeed they internally use the `select` module, which, on Windows, only supports sockets -- though on Unixy OSs it can also support any file descriptor).

For a more general (though also mostly networking oriented, but not *limited* to that) support for asynchronous (event-driven) programming, check out the [twisted](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/) third-party package.

Answer (score 19):

Good news everyone!

**Python 3.4 would include brand new ambitious asynchronous programming [implementation](http://www.slideshare.net/megafeihong/tulip-24190096)!**

It is currently called [tulip](https://code.google.com/p/tulip/source/list) and already has an [active following](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/python-tulip).

As described in [PEP 3153: Asynchronous IO support](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3153/) and [PEP 3156: Asynchronous IO Support Rebooted](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3156/):

> People who want to write asynchronous code in Python right now have a few options:
>
> - asyncore and asynchat;
> - something bespoke, most likely based on the select module;
> - using a third party library, such as [Twisted](http://www.twistedmatrix.com/) or [gevent](http://www.gevent.org/).
>
> Unfortunately, each of these options has its downsides, which this PEP tries to address.
>
> Despite having been part of the Python standard library for a long time, the asyncore module suffers from fundamental flaws following from an inflexible API that does not stand up to the expectations of a modern asynchronous networking module.
>
> Moreover, its approach is too simplistic to provide developers with all the tools they need in order to fully exploit the potential of asynchronous networking.
>
> The most popular solution right now used in production involves the use of third party libraries. These often provide satisfactory solutions, but there is a lack of compatibility between these libraries, which tends to make codebases very tightly coupled to the library they use.
>
> This current lack of portability between different asynchronous IO libraries causes a lot of duplicated effort for third party library developers. A sufficiently powerful abstraction could mean that asynchronous code gets written once, but used everywhere.

Here is the [brief overview](http://www.slideshare.net/megafeihong/tulip-24190096) of it's abilities.

Comment: Sounds crazy that someone actually wants to implement a useful way to do async programming in Python.

Comment: @MestreLion: This area has been ignored for such a long time.

Comment: @PavelŠimerda: what area has been ignored? async io implementation in python or async io as a concept/pattern in general programming?

Comment: I live in the context of Python, C and Linux. In that context, I believe async io has been neglected in general but even more so in Python. But I'm not talking about creating an async library, I'm talking about a general way to do implementation-agnostic async logic in Python application. The PEP above seems to be the first serious progress. We're getting a bit chatty, though, and I don't think our discussion makes a great addition to this SO answer. Feel free to find me on Freenode as pavlix.

Answer (score 14):

The other respondents are pointing you to Twisted, which is a great and very comprehensive framework but in my opinion it has a very un-pythonic design. Also, AFAICT, you have to use the Twisted main loop, which may be a problem for you if you're already using something else that provides its own loop.

Here is a contrived example that would demonstrate using the `threading` module:

```
from threading import Thread

def background_stuff():
  while True:
    print "I am doing some stuff"

t = Thread(target=background_stuff)
t.start()

# Continue doing some other stuff now
```

However, in pretty much every useful case, you will want to communicate between threads. You should look into [synchronization primitives](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synchronization_primitive), and become familiar with the concept of [concurrency](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concurrency_%28computer_science%29) and the related issues.

The `threading` module provides many such primitives for you to use, if you know how to use them.

Comment: While multiprocessing (and multithreading) is useful, that doesn't mean it's a solution for everything, nor it does mean that it's always a good substitute for event-driven programming using a main loop.

Answer (score 3):

You may well want to checkout the Twisted library for Python. They provide many useful tools.

1. [A little primer](http://jessenoller.com/2009/02/11/twisted-hello-asynchronous-programming/1.)
2. [Defer and Related stuff](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/defer.html)

Answer (score 1):

You may see my Python Asynchronous Programming tool: http://www.ideawu.com/blog/2010/08/delegate-in-pythonpython-asynchronous-programming.html

```
import time, random, sys
from delegate import *

def proc(a):
    time.sleep(random.random())
    return str(a)

def proc_callback(handle, args=None):
    ret = d.end(handle)

d = Delegate()
d.init(2) # number of workers

handle = d.begin(proc, '12345', proc_callback, 'test')
sys.stdin.readline()

d.free()
```