# Sleeping a Thread until certain time in Python

Tags: python, multithreading, datetime, sleep, timedelta

I've written a script that creates threads which sleep themselves until a certain time of day before sending an email. Some run at 4pm on the day the script is run, others run at 7am the next morning.

My problem is that the threads that are supposed to run at 4pm often won't run until 5pm or 6pm, whereas the ones at 7am always run right on time. The script is typically started between 10am-1pm. I'm using Python 2.6.6

The code, in a nutshell, is as follows:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import threading

def main():
  today = datetime.now()
  today_at_4pm = today.replace(hour=16, minute=0, second=0)

  tomorrow = today + timedelta(days=1)
  tomorrow_at_7am = tomorrow.replace(hour=7, minute=0, second=0)

  message = "some message"
  threading.Thread(target=dispatchEmail, args=(message, today_at_4pm)).start()
  threading.Thread(target=dispatchEmail, args=(message, tomorrow_at_7am)).start()


def dispatchEmail(message, time_to_send):
  now = datetime.now()

  if now < time_to_send:
    time_diff = time_to_send - now
    diff_in_seconds = (time_diff.days * 86400) + time_diff.seconds
    sleep(diff_in_seconds)

  sendEmail(message)

def sendEmail(message):
  print message

if __name__ == '__main__': main()
```

I can't pin down the problem because it's inconsistent when it sends it and I don't have any problem running it on short time periods. Also the diff_in_seconds calculation appears to be accurate.

I think the error lies in the sleep part or in my misunderstanding of how threads work. Any help is greatly appreciated.

For those who think I should seperate the scripts and use crontasks -- I'd prefer not to because of how the actual contents of the message are being read/tracked from files.

UPDATE

I found the threading.Timer method via the python sched docs. This allows me to run the function after a certain period of time. I moved the sleep time calculation out of the dispatchEmail which allowed me to get rid of it:

```
def timeDifference(now, time_to_send):
  if now < time_to_send:
    time_difference = time_to_send - now
    return (time_difference.days * 86400) + time_difference.seconds
  else:
    return 0

time_until_4pm = timeDifference(datetime.now(), today_at_4pm)
time_until_7am = timeDifference(datetime.now(), tomorrow_at_7am)

threading.Timer(time_until_4pm, sendEmail, (message))
threading.Timer(time_until_7am, sendEmail, (message))
```

Are there any nuances about this that I need to be aware about?

Comment: Take a look at: https://github.com/dbader/schedule

Comment: I'd suggest using the UTC epoch time with `time.time()` to get an accurate time perhaps.

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: `sleep()` may be interrupted by a signal on some Python versions. Use a  loop instead, [code example `sleep_until()` function](https://gist.github.com/zed/7770492)

Comment: @Tim Thanks for the suggestion. I'm using datetime because I also use the formatted datetimes in my emails and logs. A difference in seconds isn't important to me.. it's hours that are causing issue.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I'm using Centos 6

Comment: My question is: why not `cron`?

Comment: @NightShadeQueen I intend to use cron to trigger my script once per day, but this is a very simplified example of how email contents and recipients are determined and logged. Running it on separate days would have more complicated logic than this.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16940841/python-sleep-some-code-not-all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use thread sleeping. This is absolutely the wrong approach to the problem. If you don't want to use crons (I assume you mean literal linux cron jobs), use something like this https://docs.python.org/2/library/sched.html

Comment: This would be more what hes looking for: https://github.com/dbader/schedule, you can easily specify times with this library

Comment: Sure, there are plenty of scheduling libraries available. This is just the one in the stdlib.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm going to be queuing many jobs that run at 4pm and many more that run at 7am but the sched docs say that I can't queue tasks before the currently pending one runs, which is some concern. The threading.Timer class, which is recommended in the docs, looks like what I want, are there any issues I have to know about for that?

Comment: Can you please explain why thread sleeping is "absolutely the wrong approach"? I'm new to using them and they seem like a good way to schedule multiple overlapping tasks.

Comment: A little old of an answer, but upvoting @TomSitter's question/comment that thread sleeping is "absolutely the wrong approach" needs some support. Saying it's absolutely wrong is a bold claim to make-- it might well be right, but without any justification is't just a random claim on the internet.