# Python Threading - Make threads start without waiting for previous thread to finish

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7

I want all of my threads to start at the same time, but in my code, it waits for the previous thread to finish it's process before starting a new one. I want all of the threads to start in parallel.

My Code:

```
class Main(object):

    start = True
    config = True
    givenName = True

    def obscure(self, i):
        i = i

        while self.start:
            Config.userInfo(i)
            break
        while self.config:
            Config.open()
            break
        while self.givenName:
            Browser.openSession()
            break

Main = Main()

while __name__=='__main__':
    Config.userInfo()
    Config.open()
    for i in range(len(Config.names)):
        Task = Thread(target=Main.obscure(i))
        Task.start()
    break
```

Comment: It shouldn't be waiting since you're not using join anywhere. What are the other pieces of your code?

Comment: Why do you think it is waiting?

Comment: @wwii because when i receive the end of my code (opening web browser) the next thread starts its beginning process (prints some code)

Comment: @atru i just edited the post with my full file

Comment: Keep in mind that multi-threading is not multi-processing. Python will only run one thread at a time, even though many may be "active" at the same time.
A few other notes:
Everywhere you have a `while` statement, it can be replaced with an `if` and remove the `break` statements.
The `i = i` statement has no effect, you can remove it.

Comment: @JohnAnderson true indeed. The only exception is if it involved parallel IO, here's one [reference](https://www.ploggingdev.com/2017/01/multiprocessing-and-multithreading-in-python-3/), but there's more. In fact, in one of my programs that had some heavy data processing (data feed from files), the multithreading module helped a lot. It reduced the processing time considerably.

Comment: @JohnAnderson so if i wanted 100 separate processes running concurrently, I should be using multiprocessing instead of multithreading?

Comment: I just tried using multiprocessing and i keep getting the same problem, when timing the program multithreading is faster, but neither of them accomplish my goal of concurrent parallelism

Comment: @Michael, yes, if you really want concurrency, you need to use multiprocessing. There are limitations, of course. Multiprocessing comes with the overhead of creating new processes, and you will not get more concurrent processes beyond the number of cpus/cores that you have. 1000 separate processe will likely not be helpful, unless each process is doing a significant amount of work and you are running on a super computer with over 1000 cpus. A better approach might be to use multiprocessing.Pool.

Answer (score 4):

This line is the main problem:

```
Task = Thread(target=Main.obscure(i))
```

`target` is passed the result of *calling* `Main.obscure(i)`, *not* the function to be run in the thread.  You are currently running the function in the main thread then passing, essentially, `target=None`.

You want:

```
Task = Thread(target=Main.obscure, args=(i,))
```

Then, `Thread` will arrange to call `Main.obscure` with the listed arguments inside the thread.

Also, `Main = Main()` overwrites the `class Main` declaration with an instance of Main...but you'll never be able to make another instance since you've lost the reference to the class.  Use another name, such as `main = Main()`.