# How to run a function in the background-Django

Tags: django, jobs, background-task

I want to run an API call after every 5 mins in the app. I want to generate a notification whenever new data is added to the database through the API.So to check this I need to run the task in background to make it a real time application.

How can I achieve this task in Django?

I am facing multiple errors while using django background_tasks so I don't want to use it. Celery is not compatible with windows. Is there any other option whose tutorial is available also

Comment: What kind of errors are you facing with background tasks?

Comment: Celery is not compatible ? Weird, are you sure ?

Comment: @Moha369 Yes I am sure. Celery no longer officially supports Windows since Celery version 4.x. And while Celery 3 does support Windows, it is not compatible with Celery 4.

Comment: @DanielHolmes When I added 'background_tasks' to my installed apps and runs the server it gives me the following error  `File "C:\Users\kiran.tanweer\Envs\dash\lib\site-packages\background_task\models.py", line 8, in <module>
    from StringIO import StringIO
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'StringIO'`

Comment: now I have resolved previous issue, here another error comes up `cannot import name 'background' from 'background_task' (unknown location)` @DanielHolmes

Comment: You may need to explain your setup environment or show some code. Perhaps ask another question based on the error. I'm not aware of any alternative to Celery beside django-background-tasks.

Comment: Don't know about Windows, but if Celery might be overkill anyway you could write a custom admin (`./manage.py xxx`) command and a `cron` script to run it every five minutes. So you might just need a Windows equivalent of cron.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16940841/python-sleep-some-code-not-all

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned in your another question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57289791/how-can-i-import-background-from-background-tasks-in-django-method-gives-error) ,

1. you previously have installed [django-background-task](https://pypi.org/project/django-background-task/) instead of [django-background-tasks](https://pypi.org/project/django-background-tasks/) [notice the difference between task and tasks]. So you have got *ImportError: cannot import name 'background' from 'background_task'.*
2. Later you installed the proper one i.e django-background-tasks and then you uninstalled django-background-task which also uninstalled some of the dependencies of django-background-tasks.

**SOLUTION**: Uninstall both packages first. Then `pip install django-background-tasks`