# How can I import background from background_tasks in django. method gives error

Tags: django, background-task

I want to use django background-task
but `from background_task import background` gives error

How can I remove this error from my code.
So far I have followed the documentation and have implemented this.

views.py

```
from background_task import background

@background(schedule=60)
def main(request):

    # First we have to create our client
    client =RestApiClient(version='9.0')
```

settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'accounts.apps.AccountsConfig',
    'offense',
    'background_task',


]


Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\kiran.tanweer\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\Lib\threading.py", line 917, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "c:\users\kiran.tanweer\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\Lib\threading.py", line 865, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\kiran.tanweer\Envs\dash\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 54, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\kiran.tanweer\Envs\dash\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 117, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "C:\Users\kiran.tanweer\Envs\dash\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 390, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "C:\Users\kiran.tanweer\Envs\dash\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 377, in _run_checks
    return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\kiran.tanweer\Envs\dash\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\registry.py", line 72, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "C:\Users\kiran.tanweer\Envs\dash\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 13, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "C:\Users\kiran.tanweer\Envs\dash\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 23, in check_resolver
    return check_method()
  File "C:\Users\kiran.tanweer\Envs\dash\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 398, in check
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:
  File "C:\Users\kiran.tanweer\Envs\dash\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 80, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\kiran.tanweer\Envs\dash\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 579, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "C:\Users\kiran.tanweer\Envs\dash\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 80, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\kiran.tanweer\Envs\dash\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 572, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "C:\Users\kiran.tanweer\Envs\dash\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\kiran.tanweer\Documents\dashboard-latest\telenor\telenor\urls.py", line 26, in <module>
    from . import views
  File "C:\Users\kiran.tanweer\Documents\dashboard-latest\telenor\telenor\views.py", line 425, in <module>
    from background_task import background
ImportError: cannot import name 'background' from 'background_task' (unknown location)
```

Comment: You did install `pip install django-background-tasks` (in your virtual environment)? Can you see this in `pip freeze`?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem  amqp==1.4.9
anyjson==0.3.3
billiard==3.3.0.23
celery==3.1.18
Django==2.2.3
django-background-tasks==1.2.0
django-compat==1.0.15
kombu==3.0.37
mysql-connector-python==8.0.17
mysqlclient==1.4.2
protobuf==3.9.0
pytz==2019.1
six==1.12.0
sqlparse==0.3.0

Comment: It does look like the module has not been installed in the environment you are running. Another thing is that the django-background-tasks library wants the tasks to be put in `tasks.py` for the auto discovery to work. So not in `views.py`. Don't know if that will solve this problem, though.