# Is there a variation of the while loop that will only run the clause once until a change occurs?

Tags: python

Sorry about the title, this is a bit of a tough question to phrase. I'm using Python. Basically, I want the program to check a variable indefinitely. If the variable goes above 100 for example, I want code block A to run **only once**, and then I want the program to do nothing until the variable goes back below 100, then run code block B, and wait again until the variable goes back above 100, and then run block A again, and repeat.

The current setup I've written is as follows:

```
while on = True:
    if value_ind >= 100:
        open_time = time()
    else: 
        close_time = time()
        calculate_time_open(open_time, close_time)
```

The obvious problem here is that whichever if/else code block is true will run itself indefinitely, and create multiple entries in my lists for only one event. So, how would I make the code blocks run only once and then wait for a change instead of repeating constantly while waiting for a change? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please read about asynchronous programming [Topic on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3221314/asynchronous-programming-in-python)

Comment: You may not need to use `while`, can you just make this work with the `if` statement?

Comment: It needs to run constantly. Also, no set-time delay will work as this application is sensor-based.

Comment: Have you thought the way you're doing it is wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a state machine: your program is in one of two state: "waiting for a high/low value" and behaves appropriately:

```
THRESHOLD = 100

waiting_for_high_value = True  # False means: waiting for low value

while True:  # Infinite loop (or "while on", if "on" is a changing variable)
    if waiting_for_high_value:
        if value_ind >= THRESHOLD:
            open_time = time()
            waiting_for_high_value = False
    else:  # Waiting for a low value:
        if value < THRESHOLD:
            close_time = time()
            calculate_time_open(open_time, close_time)
            waiting_for_high_value = True
```

Now, you do need to update you test value `value_ind` somewhere during the loop. This is best done through a *local* variable (and not by changing a global variable as an invisible side effect).

PS: The answer above can be generalized to any number of states, and is convenient for adding some code that must be done continuously while waiting. In your particular case, though, you toggle between two states, and maybe there is not much to do while waiting for a change, so Stefan Pochmann's answer might be appropriate too (unless it forces you to duplicate code in the two "wait" loops).

Comment: Why is a local variable better than a global one? The variable is only being used for this function, but I have all my global variables in the same area so it's easy to find them if needed.

Comment: The reason for avoiding global variables as much as you can is that changes to these variables are _invisible_ unless you read "a lot" of code. "A lot" means "way too much compared to what you would have to read if local variables had been used". In practice, the situation is even worse, with global variables: you read code, you don't understand why there is a `while on == True` despite the fact that `on` does not seem to be changed, so you're starting to suspect that a global variable is updated somewhere. Then you have to check every single call in the loop that you were looking at, etc.

Comment: Concretely, it is often not complicated (and always way more legible) to use locals instead of globals.

Comment: Fair enough, I understand what you're saying. The program I'm writing right now is going to be very short so I don't think the global variables will be a problem in this case, but I do see how it can turn into a mess when working with large programs.

Comment: "So, how would I make the code blocks run only once and then wait for a change instead of repeating constantly while waiting for a change? Thanks in advance." I think your answer does not solve the problem. @EOL

Comment: @Elyasin Can you expand about how this answer would not solve the problem? For example, when `value_ind` goes below the threshold, `calculate_time_open()` is called (once) and then `waiting_for_high_value` toggles to `True`. Thus, `calculate_time_open()` will _not_ be called again "while we wait for a change" (`value_ind` going this time _above_ the threshold), so this "block" "runs only once". As far as I understand, this is what the question asks for.

Comment: You are right @EOL. I am sorry, my brain played tricks with me. I cannot change my vote. If you edit, I could upvote your answer.

Comment: @Elyasin Thank you for checking this. I did edit my answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
while True:

    # wait until the variable goes over 100, then do block A once
    while value_ind <= 100:
        pass
    <block A here>

    # wait until the variable goes below 100, then do block B once
    while value_ind => 100:
        pass
    <block B here>
```

This solves your repetition issue. You might better actually *wait* rather than constantly checking the variable, though, although it depends on what you're actually doing.

Added: Here it is with the actual blocks A and B from your code and using `not`, which maybe makes it nicer. One of them with parentheses which maybe highlights the condition better. (And with `pass` not on an extra line... I think that's ok here):

```
while True:
    while not value_ind > 100: pass
    open_time = time()

    while not (value_ind < 100): pass
    close_time = time()
    calculate_time_open(open_time, close_time)
```

Comment: @EOL I just realized we both rather overlooked something - the "on = True" part.   If that's needed, then your solution can handle that trivially, in mine I'd probably replace the `pass` with `if not on: return` or so, depending on the bigger picture.

Comment: @StefanPochmann I'm a new programmer, I don't understand exactly what `pass` does. In the documentation it says that it does nothing, which isn't really a very good description. Does `pass` pause the program? What is the point of having `pass` if it does nothing? Wouldn't the program run the same way without it there? Also the `on == True` was bad, just `on` is better.

Comment: @user1917407 Can you give me the link to the documentation of `pass` that you saw?

Comment: @StefanPochmann https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html See 4.5: "The `pass` statement does nothing."

Comment: @user1917407 Yes, and the very next sentence directly following that without even a line break explains the purpose.

Comment: @StefanPochmann I'm a new programmer, I don't understand exactly what pass does. Does pass pause the program? What is the point of having pass if it does nothing?

Comment: @user1917407 It does **nothing**. **NOTHING!** No, it doesn't stop the program, as that would be doing **something**. Its sole purpose is to **be** something in the source code so that Python isn't confused about your loop or so being empty.

Comment: Why even answer questions on this forum if you're just going to get mad when someone asks a question? What's simple for you might not be simple for everyone, relax.

Comment: "So, how would I make the code blocks run only once and then wait for a change instead of repeating constantly while waiting for a change? Thanks in advance." I think your answer does not solve the problem. @user1917407

Comment: I am mistaken. You are right I think. I don't know why, but last night, when I saw the answers I convinced myself they were not correct. Sorry man. I'll upvote, if you can edit the answer (voting is locked for me now until the answer is edited, sorry).