# Is there a way to make a loop that runs in the background while other code continues to run in python?

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

I'm really new to programming, I was wondering if there was a way to run a while loop in the background of code already running in Python?

I was thinking of something like

`While True:
    print("gibberish")
print("pass")`

with an output of something like:

'gibberish
gibberish
pass
gibberish.....'

(It doesn't have to be in this order as long as I get a similar result)

Comment: You should research multiprocessing/multithreading.

Comment: Take a look to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/3221320/3920623

Comment: `threading.Thread`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating Threads in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2905965/creating-threads-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer to the following code.

```
import threading

def func1():
    for i in range(10):
        print("gibberish")

def func2():
    print("pass")

t1 = threading.Thread(target=func1)
t2 = threading.Thread(target=func2)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    t1.start()
    t2.start()
```

What it does is, runs the methods `func1` and `func2` concurrently so that the provided methods run as background task for each other.

Answer (score 2):

You can use either [`multiprocessing`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html) or [`threading`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html):

```
def background_code():
    while some_condition:
        print("gibberish")

...
thread = threading.Thread(target=background_code, args=(), kwargs={})
thread.start()
print("pass")
...
```

Both `multiprocessing` and `threading` have very similar APIs, and which one to use depends on your use case - the distinction between processes and threads is not one for this question. You're *probably* going to want `threading` for what you're currently working on, but there are different situations in which you'd prefer one or the other.

Comment: I don't think this would ever print `"pass"`.

Comment: This is true; however, it most closely resembles the code put forth in the question and I think it's pretty obvious

Comment: I believe it would be most useful for future readers if you could demonstrate how to run the `while` loop in another thread while doing something else (such as printing "pass") in the main thread.

Comment: @Selcuk Good idea. Edited accordingly.

Comment: coroutines are an alternative to both multiprocessing and threading (not disagreeing with these choices at all) -- just providing a 3rd option

Answer (score 0):

Here is something similar using `asyncio` (requires python 3.7+):

```
import asyncio

async def loop():
    while True:
        print("gibberish")
        await asyncio.sleep(0.5)

async def main():
    future = asyncio.ensure_future(loop())
    for i in range(100):
        print("pass")
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
    future.cancel()
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(main())
```

This will print two `gibberish` for each `pass`. You can change the sleep timing to change the ratio.

Here, `main` and `loop` are [coroutines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coroutine), where only one is executed at a time. The `await ...` calls are points where execution is potentially yielded to other coroutines.