# Multi-tasking with Multiprocessing or Threading or Asyncio, depending on the Scenario

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, python-requests, multiprocessing, python-asyncio

I have my codes ready for 1 at a time performance, I wanna upgrade it to something fancy, multi-tasking. I am seeking helps about what I can use to achieve my goal.

my codes performs in this order: parsing multi-pages, parsing multi-posts, parsing multi-images. I tried to do multi-pages with multi-processing with pool.map(), it came out with KeyError of Daemonic can't have children processes. My understanding of this multi-tasking procedure is that parsing pages are fast, parsing posts and images can be really long.

What if I do parsing posts and parsing images together on single page, can it be allowed?

Which modules should i use to do so? thread? multiprocessing? asyncio? I went through a lot lately, I am struggling with what I should use.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3221314/asynchronous-programming-in-python

Comment: I am also confused with pool.map(), I can only carry one variable with it, I can't carry any other variables with it, such as path_outputs, the only variable which is useful in pool.map() links.

Comment: everyone has its own scenarios, and everyone has its own skill sets, and no one is on the same level of python. Like I said I read a lot already. I just wanna see something more concrete, a clear direction or guidance. Please Chief!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So off the top of my head you can look at 2 things.

1) Asyncio (be careful this example uses threading and is not thread safe specifically the function asyncio.gather)

```
import asyncio
for work in [1,2,3,4,5]:
    tasks.append(method_to_be_called(work))

results = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
```

2) Asyncio + multiprocessing
https://github.com/jreese/aiomultiprocess

Comment: sweet chief, this new module seems pretty awesome, i am going to give it a try, and see how it goes.