# Is it right to append item into the same list by multi-thread without lock?

Tags: python, multithreading

Hrere's the detail question:

I want use multi-thread way to do a batch-http-request work, then gather all these result into a list and sort all items.

So I want to define a empty list `origin_list` in main process first, and start some threads to just append result into this list after pass `origin_list` to ervery thread.

And It seemed that I got the expected results in then end, so I think I got the right result list finally without thread lock for the list is a mutable object, am I right?

My main codes are as below:

```py
def do_request_work(final_item_list,request_url):
    request_results = request.get(request_url).text
    # do request work
    finnal_item_list.append(request_results )


def do_sort_work(final_item_list):
    # do sort work 
    return final_item_list


def main():

    f_item_list = []
    request_list = [url1, url2, ...]

    with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=20) as executor:
        executor.map(
            partial(
                do_request_work,
                f_item_list
                ),
            request_list)

    sorted_list = do_sort_work(f_item_list)
```

Any commentary is very welcome. great thanks.

Comment: Which version of python are you using? Have you looked at asyncio?

Comment: Just looking at it quickly looks like this will not be thread safe. Might be better to do a return on ```def do_request_work(final_item_list,request_url):``` and then append the results to a list.

Comment: @ChristoGoosen `python3.5+`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, that this is a quite questionable solution even without taking thread safety into account.

First of all `python` has [GIL](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock), which

> In CPython, the global interpreter lock, or GIL, is a mutex that
>   protects access to Python objects, preventing multiple threads from
>   executing Python bytecodes at once.

Thus, I doubt about much performance benefit here, even noting that

> potentially blocking or long-running operations, such as I/O, image
>   processing, and NumPy number crunching, happen outside the GIL.

all `python` work will be executed one thread in a time.

From the other perspective, the same lock may help you with the thread safety here, so only one thread will modify `final_item_list` in a time, but I am not sure.

Anyway, I would use `multiprocessing` [module](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/multiprocessing.html) here with integrated parallel `map`:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def do_request_work(request_url):
    request_results = request.get(request_url).text
    # do request work
    return request_results

if __name__ == '__main__':
    request_list = [url1, url2, ...]

    with Pool(20) as p:
        f_item_list = p.map(do_request_work, request_list)
```

Which will guarantee you parallel lock-free execution of requests, since every process will receive only their part of work and just return the result, when ready.

Comment: Thanks for replying, your solution is great

Comment: But I'm still wondering  if the code above is right as there were many http-request, it would be faster using multi-thread than multi-process

Answer (score 0):

Look at this thread: [I'm seeking advise on multi-tasking on Python36 platform, Procedure setup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56160642/im-seeking-advise-on-multi-tasking-on-python36-platform-procedure-setup/56172685#56172685).

Relevant to python3.5+

```
Running Tasks Concurrently¶
awaitable asyncio.gather(*aws, loop=None, return_exceptions=False)
Run awaitable objects in the aws sequence concurrently.
```

I use this very often, just be aware that its not thread-safe, so do not change values inside, otherwise you will have use deepcopy.

Other things to look at:

- https://github.com/kennethreitz/grequests
- https://github.com/jreese/aiomultiprocess
- aiohttp